VBA help deleting rows that contain a 0 in a column
I need help with the VBA code the following:
I have an excel workbook, and within the sheet named "S4 Data" I want to convert all the data in column H to values instead of custom. I then want to go through the data and if the value in column H is 0, delete the entire row. There are more than 45000 rows so it should be efficient. I've done the following, but I keep getting Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error.
Sub ConvertAndDeleteRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rowsToDelete As Collection
    Dim arr as Variant

    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S4 Data")
    
    ' Find the last row in column H
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Convert all data in column H to values
    With ws
        .Columns("H").NumberFormat = "General"
        .Columns("H").Value = .Columns("H").Value
    End With

    arr = .Range(Cells(2, "H"), Cells(lastRow, "H"))

    Set delRange = .Rows(lastRow + 1)   
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If arr(i, 2) = 0 Then
            Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Rows(i))
        End If
    Next i
    
    End With
    delRange.Delete

End Sub


Another proposal without loops:
Sub ConvertAndDeleteRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rowsToDelete As Range

    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S4 Data")
    
    ' Find the last row in column H
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Convert all data in column H to values
    With ws.Range("H1:H" & lastRow)
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    ' Empty cells with 0 value
    ws.Range("H1:H" & lastRow).Replace 0, vbNullString, xlWhole
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rowsToDelete = ws.Range("H1:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rowsToDelete Is Nothing Then _
        rowsToDelete.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub


Could you please take a look at the new question I posted/?

This code loops through column H data in an array and use the UNION method to generate the range of rows to delete. (Not check the speed compared to other sol's.)
Sub ConvertAndDeleteRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rowsToDelete As Collection
    Dim arr
    Dim delrange As Range

    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S4 Data")
    
    ' Find the last row in column H
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Convert all data in column H to values
    With ws
        .Range(.Cells(1, "H"), .Cells(lastRow, "H")).NumberFormat = "General"
        .Range(.Cells(1, "H"), .Cells(lastRow, "H")).Value = .Range(.Cells(1, "H"), .Cells(lastRow, "H")).Value
    
    ' Initialize the collection to store rows to delete
    'Set rowsToDelete = New Collection
    arr = .Range(.Cells(1, "H"), .Cells(lastRow, "H"))
    ' Loop through the rows and collect rows to delete
    Set delrange = .Rows(lastRow + 1)
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If arr(i, 1) = 0 Then
            Set delrange = Union(delrange, .Rows(i))
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Delete rows in reverse order to avoid shifting issues
    'For i = rowsToDelete.Count To 1 Step -1
    '    ws.Rows(rowsToDelete(i)).Delete
    'Next i
    End With
    delrange.Delete

End Sub
    

    


Thanks, I just tried that and it doesn't work either. It says Compile error: Invalid or unuqualified reference on the arr = Range... line

Stil the same issue, here's what I did. And by the way, I have a header in row 1, so I changed a few small things:

Yup, I updated what I did on the main code above, also added in your line but there's an issue with .Cells(2, "H"),....

Yep tried that as well and still not working

I edited my answer which now works on any module. Try it. It doesn't matter if the first row is a header if the H column has something in it.

Another solution seemed to work instead, though it took 20+ min to run. Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate the quick responses

tried it again and it's working, thank you so much!

Delete Auto-Filtered Rows (Single Criteria)


You could use the Range.AutoFilter method combined with the Range.SpecialCells method.

Sub ConvertAndDeleteRows()

    ' Define constants.
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "S4 Data"
    Const FILTER_COLUMN As Long = 8
    Const FILTER_CRITERION As String = "2"
    
    ' Reference the main objects: workbook, worksheet and list range
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Check if no data.
    If rg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data in list!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Store the 'AutoFilterMode state' in a Boolean variable
    ' and turn off auto-filtering.
    Dim WasInAutoFiltereMode As Boolean
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        WasInAutoFiltereMode = True
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    ' Reference the data range (no headers) and the data filter column range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = drg.Columns(FILTER_COLUMN)
            
    ' Convert to General and to values.
    With crg
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
        
    ' Filter the list range.
    rg.AutoFilter Field:=FILTER_COLUMN, Criteria1:=FILTER_CRITERION
    
    ' Attempt to reference the filtered rows of the data range (no headers).
    Dim frg As Range:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set frg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Restore 'AutoFilterMode state'.
    If WasInAutoFiltereMode Then ws.ShowAllData Else ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Check if no filtered rows.
    If frg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cells equal to """ & FILTER_CRITERION _
            & """ found in range """ & crg.Address(0, 0) & """!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Store the number of filtered rows in a Long variable.
    Dim RowsFound As Long:
    RowsFound = Intersect(frg, frg.Cells(1).EntireColumn).Cells.Count
    
    ' Delete filtered rows.
    frg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    
    ' Inform.¸¸¸¸
    MsgBox RowsFound & " filtered row" & IIf(RowsFound = 1, "", "s") _
        & " deleted.", vbInformation

End Sub


It can easily be rewritten to handle multiple criteria, e.g. blanks, by using an array (e.g. Dim FILTER_CRITERIA() As Variant: FILTER_CRITERIA = Array("0", "")) with the AutoFilter's Operator parameter set to xlFilterValues. Also, the No cells... message would have to be changed.

